# Prevent float to int conversion when deserializing with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have a JSON payload with the following structure:

```
{
"age": 12
}
```

It is mapped to the following class:

```
public class Student {

    private Integer age;

    public Integer getAge(){return age;}
    public void setAge(Integer age){this.age = age;}
}
```

At the moment, if the user submits a float value for the `age`, the decimals are ignored and the only the integer part is accepted. What I want to do is prevent the user from submitting a payload with a float value for the `age` (see below) and throw an exception (something like "invalid JSON value for field 'age' at line 8 col 5" - as is the standard message when deserialization fails).

```
{
"age": 12.7 // will be truncated to 12
}
```

I was thinking of implementing a custom deserializer for numeric values, but I was wondering if there is a simpler way to achieve this.

Comment: Although is a bit unusual, can't you make your age be a double? You can of course manipulate the bits of 12.7 to get the integer value associated with it, but I doubt you'll ever want this.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Unfortunately, no, as the client requirement is that the age should be an Integer value.


**Later Edit:** indeed, manipulating the bits is a bit overkill. I would only like to use this as a very last resort :)

Comment: Maybe use some regular expression to look for the existence of a '.'? throw an exception if it returns true? Or maybe just use 'instanceof Integer'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `setter` method will be called when converting json string into java object using [`ObjectMapper`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.3/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html)'s [`readValue()`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.3/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html#readValue%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) method where you can check for value. Look at the setter method's signature that accepts `String` instead of `Integer`.

sample code:

```
class Student {

    private int age;    
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String ageString) {
        System.out.println("called");
        try {
            age = Integer.parseInt(ageString);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("age can't be in float");
        }
    }
}

...

try {
    Student student = new ObjectMapper().readValue("{\"age\": 12.5}", Student.class);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I will need to discuss with the client, though, and see if he approves of the solution. In any case, I will mark this as an answer since it produces the desired result.

Comment: In the end, the client discarded the solution, so the float values will be accepted as they are.

Comment: NOTE: This answer was valid at the time, but there is now a feature flag, identified in the other answer, which should be used. IMO, the feature should be disabled by default because it makes no sense.

Answer (score 17):

Toggle off ACCEPT_FLOAT_AS_INT. You can check more details at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features

Answer (score 7):

A floating-point value will be truncated to an integer value by default from Jackson 2.6. As indicated in a previous answer, setting `ACCEPT_FLOAT_AS_INT` to `false` should fix your problem.

```
@Test(expected = JsonMappingException.class)
public void shouldFailMarshalling() throws IOException {
    final String student = "{\"age\": 12.5}";
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // don't accept float as integer
    mapper.configure(ACCEPT_FLOAT_AS_INT, false);
    mapper.readValue(student, Student.class);
}
```

Comment: IMHO it's really weird that the default value of `ACCEPT_FLOAT_AS_INT` is `true`. It should never have been.

Comment: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html. Agreed @Walter Tross, this feature should have been set to disabled by default