# Java Jackson default type mapping

Tags: java, types, jackson

I'm using Jackson 2.4 to convert POJOs to/from Maps. I wrote a small test program as below.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestObjectMapper {

    private Object byteVal;
    private Object shortVal;
    private Object intVal;
    private Object longVal;
    private Object floatVal;
    private Object doubleVal;

    public TestObjectMapper() {
        byteVal = (byte) 127;
        shortVal = (short) 255;
        intVal = 10;
        longVal = 20L;
        floatVal = 1.2F;
        doubleVal = 1.4;
        System.out.println("Constructor");
        System.out.println("byteVal.getClass() = " + byteVal.getClass());
        System.out.println("shortVal.getClass() = " + shortVal.getClass());
        System.out.println("intVal.getClass() = " + intVal.getClass());
        System.out.println("longVal.getClass() = " + longVal.getClass());
        System.out.println("floatVal.getClass() = " + floatVal.getClass());
        System.out.println("doubleVal.getClass() = " + doubleVal.getClass());
        System.out.println();
    }

    public Object getByteVal() {
        return byteVal;
    }

    public Object getShortVal() {
        return shortVal;
    }

    public Object getIntVal() {
        return intVal;
    }

    public Object getLongVal() {
        return longVal;
    }

    public Object getFloatVal() {
        return floatVal;
    }

    public Object getDoubleVal() {
        return doubleVal;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TestObjectMapper t = new TestObjectMapper();
        Map map = mapper.convertValue(t, Map.class);
        System.out.println("map = " + map);
        System.out.println();
        for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
            System.out.format("map.get(\"%s\").getClass() = %s\n", key, map.get(key).getClass());
        }
        String k = "byteVal";
        System.out.format("((Integer) map.get(\"%s\")).byteValue() = %d\n",
                k, ((Integer) map.get(k)).byteValue());
        k = "floatVal";
        System.out.format("((Double) map.get(\"%s\")).floatValue() = %f\n",
                k, ((Double) map.get(k)).floatValue());
    }

}
```

which generates the following output:

```
Constructor
byteVal.getClass() = class java.lang.Byte
shortVal.getClass() = class java.lang.Short
intVal.getClass() = class java.lang.Integer
longVal.getClass() = class java.lang.Long
floatVal.getClass() = class java.lang.Float
doubleVal.getClass() = class java.lang.Double

map = {byteVal=127, shortVal=255, intVal=10, longVal=20, floatVal=1.2000000476837158, doubleVal=1.4}

map.get("byteVal").getClass() = class java.lang.Integer
map.get("shortVal").getClass() = class java.lang.Short
map.get("intVal").getClass() = class java.lang.Integer
map.get("longVal").getClass() = class java.lang.Long
map.get("floatVal").getClass() = class java.lang.Double
map.get("doubleVal").getClass() = class java.lang.Double
((Integer) map.get("byteVal")).byteValue() = 127
((Double) map.get("floatVal")).floatValue() = 1.200000
```

Why is the mapping of types correct in some cases but not in others? Is there a way of controlling this without doing any changes to my classes?

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? Are you expecting Jackson to read your mind when you don't declare any specific type on your fields?

Comment: Could you please clarify the questions? What is exactly the issue?

Comment: Difference is Byte->Integer and Float->Double. There is no Byte type in Json. So Float and Byte will be converted to Number type in JSON.

See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_data_types.htm so it makes sense as Number is double- precision floating-point format in JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes, I could have omitted taking about JSON in this case. So just looking at the mapping POJO -> Map, the types are mapped correct in some cases but not others. The type information is available in the original fields in the class.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is the mapping of types correct in some cases but not in others?

This is an expected behavior from `Jackson`. If you take account of data types supported by `JSON`, which are as below, it makes complete sense for Jackson to convert the data types of values accordingly.

- **`Number`** — a signed decimal number that may contain a fractional part and may use exponential E notation. JSON does not allow non-numbers like NaN, nor does it make any distinction between integer and floating-point. (Even though JavaScript uses a double-precision floating-point format for all its numeric values, other languages implementing JSON may encode numbers differently)
- **`String`** — a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, though characters outside the BMP must be represented as a surrogate pair. Strings are delimited with double-quotation marks and support a backslash escaping syntax.
- **`Boolean`** — either of the values true or false
- **`Array`** — an ordered list of zero or more values, each of which may be of any type. Arrays use square bracket notation with elements being comma-separated.
- **`Object`** — an unordered associative array (name/value pairs). Objects are delimited with curly brackets and use commas to separate each pair, while within each pair the colon ':' character separates the key or name from its value. All keys must be strings and should be distinct from each other within that object.
- **`null`** — An empty value, using the word null

> Is there a way of controlling this without doing any changes to my
>   classes?

It can be controlled while Jackson is used to deserialization but not at the time of serialization. Following Stack Overflow answer may be of some help to you.

[Java Jackson - prevent float to int conversion when deserializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076030/java-jackson-prevent-float-to-int-conversion-when-deserializing)

**UPDATE**

In order to convert one object to another, `ObjectMapper` first serializes the source object into a `JsonParser` object and then deserializes this `JsonParser` object into the destination type object. Hence, it makes this behavior of `ObjectMapper` quite obvious.

/

```
**
     * Actual conversion implementation: instead of using existing read
     * and write methods, much of code is inlined. Reason for this is
     * that we must avoid wrapping/unwrapping both for efficiency and
     * for correctness. If wrapping/unwrapping is actually desired,
     * caller must use explicit <code>writeValue</code> and
     * <code>readValue</code> methods.
     */
    protected Object _convert(Object fromValue, JavaType toValueType)
        throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        // sanity check for null first:
        if (fromValue == null) return null;
        /* Then use TokenBuffer, which is a JsonGenerator:
         * (see [JACKSON-175])
         */
        TokenBuffer buf = new TokenBuffer(this);
        try {
            // inlined 'writeValue' with minor changes:
            // first: disable wrapping when writing
            SerializationConfig config = getSerializationConfig().without(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
            // no need to check for closing of TokenBuffer
            _serializerProvider(config).serializeValue(buf, fromValue);

            // then matching read, inlined 'readValue' with minor mods:
            final JsonParser jp = buf.asParser();
            Object result;
            // ok to pass in existing feature flags; unwrapping handled by mapper
            final DeserializationConfig deserConfig = getDeserializationConfig();
            JsonToken t = _initForReading(jp);
            if (t == JsonToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                DeserializationContext ctxt = createDeserializationContext(jp, deserConfig);
                result = _findRootDeserializer(ctxt, toValueType).getNullValue();
            } else if (t == JsonToken.END_ARRAY || t == JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
                result = null;
            } else { // pointing to event other than null
                DeserializationContext ctxt = createDeserializationContext(jp, deserConfig);
                JsonDeserializer<Object> deser = _findRootDeserializer(ctxt, toValueType);
                // note: no handling of unwarpping
                result = deser.deserialize(jp, ctxt);
            }
            jp.close();
            return result;
        } catch (IOException e) { // should not occur, no real i/o...
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

Source code from http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.0.0-RC1/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.java#ObjectMapper.convertValue%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Class%29

Comment: I removed JSON from my original question as I realise it was not really relevant here. I'm only talking about Maps.

Comment: Thank you, that makes it clear why the mapping works like it does.