# Jackson-databind 2.5 converting float to int

Tags: jackson, jackson-databind

What is the alternate of DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_FLOAT_AS_INT in **jackson-databind** **2.5**, as this deserialization configuration is NOT available in **2.5** (its available since **2.6**)

Our application is using jackson-databind **2.5**, in which we noticed that float is being converted to int.

We though that we will need to disable value conversions, coercion. But as we are using jackson 2.5, there is **NO** *DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_FLOAT_AS_INT*

How to disable this float to int conversion in 2.5? We expect that the user should be getting the data validation exception if he is providing float, instead on int, in "age".

Following is the sample POJO

```
public class User {

    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

This is the test code (using jackson-databind 2.5):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class TestConvert {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = "{\"name\" : \"foobar\", \"age\" : 2.99}";

        //JSON from file to Object
        User user = mapper.readValue(json, User.class);

        //Object to JSON in String
        String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
        System.out.println(jsonInString);


    }

}
```

Output of above test code is:

{"name":"foobar","age":2}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Jackson - prevent float to int conversion when deserializing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076030/java-jackson-prevent-float-to-int-conversion-when-deserializing)

Answer (score 0):

Change your *User* class like this:

```
package ch.hasselba.jackson.test2;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;

public class User {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(Object age) throws JsonMappingException {

        if( age instanceof Float )
            throw new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException("Bad Age! No Floats allowed!");
        if( age instanceof Double )
            throw new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException("Bad Age! No Doubles please!");

        this.age = (Integer) age;
    }

}
```

You will receive an error like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Bad Value! No Doubles please
 at [Source: {"name" : "foobar", "age" : 2.99}; line: 1, column: 29] (through reference chain: ch.hasselba.jackson.test2.User["age"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:268)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty._throwAsIOE(SettableBeanProperty.java:537)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty._throwAsIOE(SettableBeanProperty.java:518)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:99)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:276)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3789)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2833)
    at ch.hasselba.jackson.test2.TestConvert.main(TestConvert.java:19)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Bad Value! No Doubles please
    at ch.hasselba.jackson.test2.User.setAge(User.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:97)
    ... 5 more
```

The error with Jackson 2.8.0 and the disabled *DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_FLOAT_AS_INT* looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not coerce a floating-point value ('2.99') into Integer; enable `DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_FLOAT_AS_INT` to allow
 at [Source: {"name" : "foobar", "age" : 2.99}; line: 1, column: 29] (through reference chain: ch.hasselba.jackson.test2.User["age"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:261)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportMappingException(DeserializationContext.java:1233)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._failDoubleToIntCoercion(StdDeserializer.java:1118)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseInteger(StdDeserializer.java:430)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:308)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:286)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:490)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:95)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:276)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3789)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2833)
    at ch.hasselba.jackson.test2.TestConvert.main(TestConvert.java:19)
```

Comment: Thanks....it works this way. But I am looking to handle it globally, and NOT using custom code in each POJO (wherever primitive int is being used). Is there some configuration for Jackson in 2.5, to handle this?