# Spring Boot validation takes float value in integer field

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

I'm trying to implement a POST service with request validation.

My `Controller` method looks something like below

```java
public void updateScore(@Valid ScoreRequest)
```

`ScoreRequest` looks like below

```java
import javax.validation.constraints.*;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class ScoreRequest {
    @Min(0)
    @Max(100)
    @Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 3)
    private Integer score;

    ...
}
```

It all works fine till I pass integer values for score, however If I pass fraction part as well, request  goes through and Spring somehow truncates the fraction and uses the integer part in the request.

I was expecting it to throw a validation error since datatype of score doesn't match.

It works with followling request, and uses 10 as the score value in the request object. I'm expecting it to throw an error, what am I doing wrong?

```
{"score": 10.234234}
```

**Spring Boot version: 2.0.3.RELEASE**

Comment: Jackson willjust hapilly convert it to an integer without complaining. The validation doesn't make sense either as an `Integer` never has a fraction.

Comment: Problem is that since we're not getting an error, client who used this request would assume that `10.234234` was saved correctly.

Comment: That isn't something you can fix with `@Digit`. Unless you accept a `Float` or `Double` instead of `Integer`. What you should do is disable the `ACCEPT_FLOAT_AS_INT` feature, which will then fail to map the float value to an int and lead to a serialization error.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your insight, I found the solution in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/38472723/5343269

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to debug Spring Boot's validation classes to find what was happening, but after looking at the comment by @M.Denium I searched for Jackson issues and found a related SO entry.

[Java Jackson - prevent float to int conversion when deserializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076030/java-jackson-prevent-float-to-int-conversion-when-deserializing)

I'm using answer by `@Jichao Zhang`, however Just to confirm answer by `@Eduardo Sanchez-Ros` works as well. This is what works for me.

```
ObjectMapper.configure(DESERIALIZATION_FEATURE.ACCEPT_FLOAT_AS_INT, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this annotation: `@Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 3` with Integer since it is useless to set fractions for `Integer`.

Why don't you do:

```
@Min(0)
@Max(100)
@Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 3)
private BigDecimal score;
```

Comment: You want it to throw exception ? Then do some `if`.

If (yourNumber==Math.round(yourNumber) throw YourException();

Answer (score 0):

If you closely look at the definition of the `@digits` annotation,

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
```

So this annotation can be applied to methods also. 
If you read the docs, it says this annotation can be applied to the following types

- BigDecimal
- BigInteger
- CharSequence
- byte (or Byte)
- short (or Short)
- int (or Integer)
- long (or Long)

the `integer` field of the annotation checks for the number of integral digits while the `fraction` field of the annotation checks for the number of fractional digits.

Since, you declared your field to be an Integer value. It casts the value to an integer and truncates the fractional part.
This does not fail validations as both the fields satisfy the validation.

**This annotation is ideally to be only used with `BigDecimal` type.**

Comment: One possible solution I see to fail these requests is to declare the field as `Float` and keep the `fraction` field to `0`. I am not sure if this would work.